# Number of extreme points of a convex polyhedron

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry, polyhedra, discrete-geometry

In $\mathbb{R}_+^n$ $(n\geq 1)$, let $S$ be the $(n-1)$-simplex:

$$S=\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}_+^n,\,\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=1\right\}$$

whose relative interior is denoted $\mathring S$, and $E$ be a linear subspace of dimension $n-2$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, such that $E\cap\mathring S\neq\varnothing$. Hence $E\cap\mathring S$ is a convex polyhedron with relative interior interior of dimension $n-3$ and has hence a minimum of $n-2$ extremal points.

**Question:** what is the maximal number of extreme points for $E\cap S$?

Comment: What does "relative interior" mean? My first guess is that you mean the open face but that produces something which isn't closed so I don't understand the claim that $E \cap \mathring S$ is a polyhedron.

Comment: The relative interior is the interior relative to the affine hull.

Comment: $S$ is the restriction of an hyperplane to the first orthant, so it is an $(n-1)$-simplex, actually. Or do you consider the simplex made by the convex hull of ($S \cup \{O\}$), $O$ being the origin?

Comment: It's an $(n-1)$-simplex as you said, I corrected it, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full solution but more of an educated guess. Hopefully it can be turned into one with enough work, or at the very least give some useful ideas.

**Reduction to counting triangles:**
Start by projecting the simplex into $E^\perp$, a 2-dimensional space. Now all of $E$ has collapsed into a point $O$ (which will be our "origin" on $E^\perp$).

If we assume that $E$ was in a somewhat generic position (not parallel to a facet, hopefully you can wiggle extremal solutions around). Then the number of extremal points of $E\cap \mathring S$ is the number of intersections between $E$ and $2-$dimensional facets of $S$. At the projection level, this becomes a combinatorial question:

> You are given $n$ non-zero distinct points in $\mathbb{R}^2$, which generate $n\choose 3$ triangles. How many of them can contain the origin inside?

By scaling, you can even assume the $n$ points are on the unit circle! At this point it almost feels like a discrete version of a famous Putnam question: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OkmNXy7er84. If we believe the analogy, we expect to get an asymptotic of $\frac 1 4 \frac {n^3} {6}  $.

**(not) Solving the counting problem** I don't know the answer to this problem, but we can guess it, by hoping that the extremizer comes from a regular polygon.

Start by assuming $n=2k+1$ is odd. Fix one vertex. We will have to multiply by $n$ (choice of vertex) and divide by 3 (triangle has 3 vertices). The other 2 vertices will be one on the "left" and one on the "right". Let $j$ be the number of "hops" to the right you have to do to get to the right vertex (so $j=1 \dots k$). Then you have $k+j-1$ options for the left vertex. Then

$$
\text{Tri}(2k+1) = \frac{2k+1}{3}\sum_{j=1}^k k-j+1 = \frac{2k+1}{3}\left(k^2 -\frac{k^2+k}{2}-k\right) = \frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6}
$$

A similar computation, where you count points that are in the boundary with a factor of $1/2$ (because, what else?) gives

$$
\text{Tri}(2k) = \frac 13 k(k^2-1)
$$

**Is our guess any good?** Through more rudimentary methods and still assuming somewhat generic positions (which amount to checking all possible configurations) you can do the computation for small $n$, and I got:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
n & 3 &4 & 5 & 6 & 7 &8 &9&10&11\\ \hline
 \text{Extrema}(n)& 1 &2 & 5&8&14&20 &?&?&? \\ \hline
\text{Tri}(n) & 1 & 2& 5 &8& 14 &20& 30 &40& 55\\ \hline
\end{array}
$$